# Select particular column name like disc% in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to select particular column in MySQL. But my column name is disc%. How i select?

```
select disc%(Column_Name) from PurchaseInvoicegrntable**strong text**(Table_Name)
```

Comment: Enclose in backticks. Please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html

Comment: `Select "disc%(Column_Name)" from PurchaseInvoicegrntable`